# Why is half of the smoke not showing in the reflection when I turn on "indirect only"?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, error, reflection, render-passes

I have a character that is emitting smoke and standing on a plane with glass shader. I want to render the plane with the reflections and the smoke separately. However, when I turn on "indirect only" the base of the indirect reflection disappears, resulting in a sharp transition to the rest of the reflections. When I render everything together, there is no problem. It almost looks like there is an object blocking for the reflection, but I've gone through every object, and they are not hidden. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

[image] Combined [image] Glossy indirect-pass[image] AO-pass

Comment: Well, the AO pass tells me there is something that's corresponding to those sharp step-like edges in the Glossy Indirect pass. Is there something wrong with the geometry of the plane? It doesn't look completely flat... or maybe double faces? Flipped normals?

Comment: Thank you for looking at it @GordonBrinkmann I agree that the it doesn't look straight I went in to check and the plane is as straight as can be :/ I had some flipped normals that caused other issue, sadly not this one. I merged vertices by distance but there is nothing. Thank you again!